# How would while true work in this exact case?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get it when you type RecPyrSA it will play the def RecPyrSA and I'm not sure how that could be done. I'm also new to python and not sure what to do so I just wanted to make a fun script.

```
from math import e


def RecPyrSA():
    recpyrl=float(input("Base Length "))
    recpyrw=float(input("Base Width "))
    recpyrthl=float(input("Triangle Height On The Legth Side "))
    recpyrthw=float(input("Triangle Height On The Width Side "))
    recpyrsa=(recpyrl*recpyrw+recpyrthl*recpyrl+recpyrthw*recpyrw)
    print(recpyrsa)
def ConeSA():
    print ("type r then l")
    x=float(input("r "))
    y=float(input("l "))
    csa=(3.14*x*x)+(3.14*y*x)
    print(csa)
start=input("Type Here --> ")

while True:
    print ("For the surface area of a rectangular pyramid type RecPyrSA")
    SAstart=input("Type here ---> ")

    if SAstart == "RecPyrSA"
        RecPyrSA
        break
    else:
        print ("Incorrect Code")
        print ("Try Again")
```

Comment: The statement `RecPyrSA` does absolutely nothing - it just references the function, it doesn't actually call it.  That would be written `RecPyrSA()`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call the function.

```
RecPyrSA
```

is simply a variable with a function object in it. Once you've referenced a function object, it is called with parens

```
RecPyrSA()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function, which you do with parenthesis, `function_name()`. Also, you don't appear to use `e` from `math`, so you don't need to import that. You were also missing a colon at the end of the line: `if SAstart == "RecPyrSA"`. You should also add space on either side of operators, as according to [`PEP 8`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Also according to [`PEP 8`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), function names should be in `snake_case`.

Code with changes:

```
def rec_pyr_SA():
    recpyrl = float(input("Base Length "))
    recpyrw = float(input("Base Width "))
    recpyrthl = float(input("Triangle Height On The Legth Side "))
    recpyrthw = float(input("Triangle Height On The Width Side "))
    recpyrsa = recpyrl * recpyrw + recpyrthl * recpyrl + recpyrthw * recpyrw
    print(recpyrsa)

def cone_sa():
    print("type r then l")
    x = float(input("r "))
    y = float(input("l "))
    csa = (3.14 * x * x) + (3.14 * y * x)
    print(csa)

while True:
    print ("For the surface area of a rectangular pyramid type RecPyrSA")
    SA_start = input("Type here ---> ")

    if SA_start == "RecPyrSA":
        rec_pyr_SA()
        break
    else:
        print("Incorrect Code")
        print("Try Again")
```

Comment: adding to the PEP 8 part: function and method names too should be in `snake_case`